# How to efficiently strip tabs character from a txt format file with Python

Tags: python, string, performance, replace

The objective is strip [tabs character](https://www.howtogeek.com/89577/how-to-search-for-line-breaks-tabs-and-special-characters-in-ms-word/) that exist between two strings.

Specifically, I would like to remove the **Tab character** in between the  `*Generic` and `h_two` which is highlighted in yellow as depicted below

[image]

the expected output as viewed using Microsoft Office application in a Show Paragraph Mark is a below'

[image]

The file is from a txt format file.

One naive way is as

```
f_output.write(line.replace('*Generic \t \t', ','))
```

However, this did not work as intended.

So, there are two issues.

1. The code below replace all the tab characters instead of only in between the Generic and h_two strings

2. How to efficiently replace only the tab characters between the sub-strings?

The full code to replicate this issue is.

```
import pandas as pd

fname = 'endnote_csv_help'
'''
Step 1) Create mock df and save to csv
'''
my_list = ['col_one', 'col_two', 'col_three']
combine_list = [{'h_one', 'h_two', 'h_three'}, my_list, my_list]
df = pd.DataFrame(combine_list)
df.to_csv(f'{fname}.csv', index=False, header=False)

'''
Step 2) Read the csv and convert to txt format
'''

df_shifted = pd.read_csv(f'{fname}.csv', header=None).shift(1, axis=0)
df_shifted.at[0, 0] = '*Generic'
df_shifted.fillna('').to_csv(f'{fname}.txt', sep='\t', index=False, header=False)

'''
Step 3) Read the txt and replace the tab character
'''



with open('endnote_csv_help.txt') as f_input, open('new_endnote_csv_help.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    for line in f_input:
        f_output.write(line.replace('*Generic \t \t', ','))
```

Note:
The thread has been updated slightly upon the response by @Kuldeep.

Comment: can you please add a snippet of your txt file, rather than an image! And also how big is your txt file?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Kuldeep, the image above can be reproduced from the step 1 and 2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

per other answer - your error is because you are reading from a file that you have opened for write.   If you want to replace multiple instances of tab with blank use a reg expr.  This expression matches 2 or more consecutive tabs with empty string

```
import re
data = '*Generic\t\t\nh_three\th_one\th_two\ncol_one\tcol_two\tcol_three\n'
re.sub("([\t][\t]+)", "", data)
```

**output**

```
'*Generic\nh_three\th_one\th_two\ncol_one\tcol_two\tcol_three\n'
```

to remove exception, read from file which is opened for read and write to file opened for write.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

fname = 'endnote_csv_help'
'''
Create mock df and save to csv
'''
my_list = ['col_one', 'col_two', 'col_three']
combine_list = [{'h_one', 'h_two', 'h_three'}, my_list, my_list]
df = pd.DataFrame(combine_list)
df.to_csv(f'{fname}.csv', index=False, header=False)

'''
# Read the csv and convert to txt format
'''

df_shifted = pd.read_csv(f'{fname}.csv', header=None).shift(1, axis=0)
df_shifted.at[0, 0] = '*Generic'
df_shifted.fillna('').to_csv(f'{fname}.txt', sep='\t', index=False, header=False)

'''
Read the txt and replace the tab character
'''

with open(f'{fname}.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = re.sub("([\t][\t]+)", "", file.read())
with open(f'{fname}.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(data)
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the response, however, you suggestion replace all the tabs in the document.However, I only wanted to remove part of the tabs character.

Comment: This replaces any two tabs, not in the limited context specified by the OP. (It's not hard to fix the regex to add the context, perhaps as lookarounds.)

Comment: You know your requirement ....  if I take as black and white then solution is `re.sub("(\*Generic)([\t][\t]+)(\nh_three)", r"\1\3", data)`

Comment: which is very brittle.  `re.sub("([\*,A-Z,a-z]*)([\t][\t]+)([\n,a-z,_]*)", r"\1\3", data)` will remove consecutive tabs between two tokens matching two other reg exp tokens.  it's really useful to learn reg expr if you want to manipulate data in this way

Comment: you need to know and understand your requirements.  the first reg expr is very stable and easy to understand if your requirement is remove consecutive tabs.  software development always needs to really consider maintainability which also covers stability of requirements

Comment: Appreciate your response Rob, but I really appreciate if you can update your answer above to include read and write the text file

Comment: Hi Rob, my request is for the future reader. As you can see above, I already got one of the suggestion working and even made it based on other suggestion. Also, Im being generous to give your approach as the accepted answer for this thread given that it satisfied the original requirement

Answer (score 1):

Input: `endnote_csv_help.txt`

```
*Generic        
h_one   h_three h_two
col_one col_two col_three
```

Output: `new_endnote_csv_help.txt`

```
*Generic,,
h_one,h_three,h_two
col_one,col_two,col_three
```

Reading a line from the input and replacing tabs the writing it to output

```
with open('endnote_csv_help.txt') as f_input, open('new_endnote_csv_help.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    for line in f_input:
        f_output.write(line.replace('\t', ','))
```

Comment: Awesome @Kuldeep. However, your solution replace all the tab character instead of only those between the *Generic and h_two

Comment: Can you please add expected output to your question!

Comment: Hi @kuldeep, I have attached new image for the expected output.

Comment: You want to swap h_three and h_one??

Comment: Hi @Kuldeep, please check the latest edit. Thanks. But I notice, .shift(1, axis=0) always mess up with the column order.But, this is not a big issue at this stage

Comment: Thanks @Kuldeep, apparently, we can replace it simply replacing \t\t with empty string

Answer (score 0):

As appear, there are two character Tab between  in between the *Generic and h_two which.

Hence, this can be replace simply by

```
replace('\t\t', '')
```

The complete code then as below

```
with open('endnote_csv_help.txt') as f_input, open('new_endnote_csv_help.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    for line in f_input:
        f_output.write(line.replace('\t\t', ''))
```

Note that, there should be no spacing between the Character Tabs symbol `\t\t`.

Thanks to the suggestion by @Kuldeep, it does provide major hint. As a result, his comment will be accepted as answer